# IOS 8 iPad App Crashes When UIActivityViewController Is Called

Tags: swift, ios8, crash, sprite-kit, uiactivityviewcontroller

When a UIActivityViewController is called on the iPhone in this app, it works perfectly, but when called on a iPad, the app crashes. Below is the code I used:

```
func shareButtonPress() {

    //when the share button is pressed, default share phrase is added, cropped image of highscore is added

    var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()

    var shareButtonHighscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as Int!

    sharingItems.append("Just hit \(shareButtonHighscore)! Beat it! #Swath")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    sharingItems.append(image)

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    var barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem! = UIBarButtonItem()

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

As you can see, I'm programming in Swift, in the SpriteKit Framework, and I don't understand why the app is crashing.

I'm receiving this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x7fc7a874bd90>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: > What can I do to fix this problem? -- 1. read the error message. 2. check docs on `UIPopoverController`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Before presenting the `UIActivityViewController`, add in this line of code:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

This way, the view controller knows in which frame of the GameViewController to appear in.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the error it says how to fix it, you need to set the barButtonItem or sourceView from which to present the popover from, in your case:

```
func shareButtonPress(pressedButton: UIBarButtonItem) { 

    ...

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = pressedButton

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `[MyGame.GameViewController shareButtonPress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f8c610'`

Comment: What can I do to correct this? I can't replace UIBarButtonItem with the name of the actual button, because the actual button is defined in GameScene.

Comment: How do you add the target to the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: This is a much better solution than others, because this view controller should be shown at top of "caller" view.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**:

Check if the device is `iPhone` or `iPad` and based on that add a `sourceView` and present the `activityController`

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = UIApplication.topViewController!.view
    UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two option, the action came from a UIBarButtonitem or UIButton that is a UIView.

```
func shareButtonPress() {

    ...

    if let actv = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
        actv.barButtonItem = someBarButton // if it is a UIBarButtonItem

        // Or if it is a view you can get the view rect
        actv.sourceView = someView
        // actv.sourceRect = someView.frame // you can also specify the CGRect
    }

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You may have to add a sender to your function like `func shareButtonPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem)` or `func shareButtonPress(sender: UIButton)`

Answer (score 1):

I added for Swift 3:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

fixed my issue.