# Xamarin.iOS UIPopoverPresentationController Exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, popover

I am having difficulty presenting a Popover with `UIPopoverPresentationController`, following what can I find from the internet, including [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_transient_content_in_a_popover) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548760/ios-8-ipad-app-crashes-when-uiactivityviewcontroller-is-called). Nothing has helped. Here's a test app I created:

**ViewController.cs**

```
  public override void ViewDidLoad()
  {
     ...

     var popupView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
     {
        Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Menu")
     };

     _menuController = new UIViewController
     {
        ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover,
        View = popupView
     };

     _presentationController = new UIPopoverPresentationController(_menuController, this)
     {
        SourceView = View,
        SourceRect = new CGRect(50, 50, 300, 300),
     };
  }
```

And I invoke on button press with:

```
  PresentViewController(_menuController, true, null);
```

I get this exception when the presentation style is `Popover`:

> UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or
>   barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `UIViewController` has a `UIPopoverPresentationController` called `PopoverPresentationController`, you can just use that to present your pop view:

```
private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var popupView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
    {
        Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Menu"),
        UserInteractionEnabled = true
    };

    _menuController = new UIViewController
    {
        ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover,
        PreferredContentSize = new CGSize(200, 200),
        View = popupView
    };

    _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = new CGRect(50, 50, 300, 300);
    _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = View;


    PresentViewController(_menuController, true, null);
}
```

I find that when we dismiss the popoverview, it will return to null. So here I recommend you to initialize it in your method every time when you show it up.

Moreover if you want to achieve the same effect on iPhone, please add the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` like:

```
public override UIModalPresentationStyle GetAdaptivePresentationStyle(UIPresentationController forPresentationController)
{
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None;
}
```

Set the delegate to it: `_menuController.PopoverPresentationController.Delegate = new MyPopOverViewDelegate();`

Comment: The key here is initializing `UIViewController.PopoverPresentationController` instead of creating a new instance. Thanks

Comment: And creating the View on each "click" prevents the exception when showing the popover more than once. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `UIPopoverPresentationController.SourceView` to a `UIView` that is outside the view controller to provide a view that becomes the anchor point, i.e. a UIView on the **parent** view controller

You say present this via a button touch, you could use that button as the source (if that location is appropriate).

```
_presentationController = new UIPopoverPresentationController(_menuController, this)
{
    SourceView = button,
    SourceRect = new CGRect(50, 50, 300, 300),
};
```

#### Example:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I must be misunderstanding something -- the `View` in my code is the top-level view, other than the app `Window` presumably. My `button` didn't work, as it's added and contained in `View`.

Comment: Are you referring to `this.ParentViewController`? Here it's null.