# How can I align my custom Popover view controller to center of ParentViewController in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile

I am currently dealing with the screen where I have to show custom PopOver view controller to the center of the ParentViewController.

I have used
`PopOverView.Center = new CGPoint(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 2, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height / 2);`

This brought the PopoverViewController to center but the Margins from all 4 sides are uneven.

Comment: PopoverViewControllers are deprecated. Have you tried using PopoverPresentationController instead?

Comment: Did you give your PopOverView a frame?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No, is it necessary ?

Comment: I think it is, give a PopOverView.center is not enough.

Comment: Did your solved your problem? Share some code and maybe I can help you.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No not yet. Right now I ma trying some other approach where I keep background color of Popup-VC(view controller) to be transparent and and design my popup inside a view in a Popup-VC.

Comment: `viewController.PreferredContentSize = new CGSize(_view.Frame.Size.Width, _view.Frame.Size.Height);`    

`viewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;`

Comment: @NIshank How do you popup the viewController? PresenetViewController? Add a subViewController?

Comment: `Popover.ContentViewController = viewController;`     `Popover.PresentFromRect(CGRect.Empty, _view, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);`  @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: The last approach worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is Popover here? I wonder why not just popup a custom View instead of a ViewController?

Comment: I also thought the the but can't do in my current project as old UI was made using [Fluent](https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout) and it was scrapped and again refreshed through storyboards, so there was very less scope of customization as classes were tightly bound.

Answer (score 0):

PopoverViewControllers are deprecated. Have you tried using PopoverPresentationControllers instead, they are centred by default? There are several examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930691/xamarin-ios-uipopoverpresentationcontroller-exception)